# Different ways to block a textbox UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, textbox, isenabled

I have two textBox and I need to leave them disabled to show a loaded information

```
<TextBox x: Name = "txt_Name" Header = "Name:" Margin = "5" Text = "{Binding NamePlacta, Mode = TwoWay}" IsEnabled = "True" />
```

The "IsEnable" property works, but visually I do not like it, I would like to block the option to edit the text but leaving a better look to the textBox.

I leave an image of how it looks and how I would like it:

[image: at the top is a textBox with IsEnable = false]

Comment: Okey the property is `ReadOnly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave IsEnabled true but set the IsReadOnly property to true also. That will keep the default style but make it uneditable.